# Script with jquery

Tags: jquery

i have this code and  it worke five minutes ago , when i restart my app it does not work , i don't know whyyyyyy :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).click(function () { 


            var div = $('.idbody');
            div.animate({ top: '20%' }, "slow"); 
            });

    </script>

<div class="idbody">
.............My html code ............
</div>
```

thank you

Comment: clear browser cache and try.

Comment: What error have you??

Comment: no error i just doesn't work :'(

Comment: @Pilot it worked 15min ago :/

Comment: do you have any error in your browser's console?

Comment: @Jai  no ..i have no error  ....

Comment: @Meryem which is your browswer would you tell us?

Comment: Google chrome and i cleared cache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

HTML Code:

```
<div class="idbody">.............My html code ............</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.idbody
        {
            background: url(images/fondbodyrepeatos.png) repeat;
            width: 400px;
            height: 250px;
            position: absolute;
            top: -50%;
            left: 32%;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 35px #014668;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding-left: 5%;
        }
```

Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).click(function () {
        var div = $('.idbody');
        $('div').animate({
            top: '+=20%'
            }, 'slow', function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/realdeepak/LSk2S/2/)

Comment: You need to place the position for that div.nice job deepak

Comment: See the demo dear: http://jsfiddle.net/realdeepak/LSk2S/1/

Comment: i saw many demo and when i try to do it with the same code  , it doesn't work too

Comment: @Meryem, check my code in this link, http://jsfiddle.net/realdeepak/LSk2S/2/

Comment: My fiddle link is working. If you are unable to check it then share your code on jsfiddle.

Comment: it dosn't work in my app , but when i open a new project for test it work

Comment: ITTT WOOOORK .....with your code and i added this files :

Answer (score 0):

It probably because of the problem with your internet connection. Try download the jquery file and keep it locally. 
save this file [jquery](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js)

Comment: what jquery file and how can i keep it locally .thank you

Answer (score 0):

ITTT WOOOORK .....with your code and i added this files :

```
<script src="Script/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Script/_jquery-2.0.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```